# How to undo the deletion of a question?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, undelete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean)
>   [How do I undelete my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101361/how-do-i-undelete-my-question)

How can we undo the deletion of a question?
Actually I deleted my own question but now I want that question back. So how can we achieve this?

Comment: @UristMcBobby Thnx

Comment: I've undeleted your question. If this happens again, just flag a different question for moderator attention and ask them to undelete your other question.